# Best open source tool to manage design documents like class diagram

Tags: open-source, document-management, editor

I need to manage a open source tool which can manage design documents like class diagram. It should let to merge multiple design documents together and those documents should be in editable format. It's favorable if I can group some documents together like prezzi. When I click on one circle, it will show the high level things. Are there any such open source tools?

Any file format is acceptable. It needs to be shared with other people. others are able to install the same software. Having ability to export as PDF or ODT is preferable

Comment: You are OK with any file format? Is it just for you only? Or will you need to share results with other people? If you need to share, will the other people be able to install the same software? Or do you need the ability to export to other formats such as PDF or ODT?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul **You are OK with any file format?** yes Is **it just for you only? Or will you need to share results with other people?** need to share with other people **If you need to share, will the other people be able to install the same software?** others are able to install the same software **do you need the ability to export to other formats such as PDF or ODT?** having ability to export as PDF or ODT is preferable

Comment: Please add these elements to your question, thanks!